# Translate CGRect from CALayer to UIImage

Tags: uikit, calayer, avcapturedevice, avcaptureoutput

I have a camera app which shows a video preview in a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` instance, which includes a CGRect (for example a frame around the user). This layer has the same size as the `UIView` which contains the layer (for instance 667x375).

How do I translate the `CGRect` from the layer's coordinate space to the image output?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself; the right way is to use the method `metadataOutputRectConverted`.

```
        let tempRect = layer.metadataOutputRectConverted(fromLayerRect: rect)
        let trans_rect = CGRect(x: tempRect.origin.x * image.size.width,
                                y: tempRect.origin.y * image.size.height,
                                width: tempRect.width * image.size.width,
                                height: tempRect.height * image.size.height)
```

Where `image` is a `UIImage` instance.